# Is there a way to find not handled errors in go code?

Tags: go

Let's assume the following code:

```
func main() {
    doStuff()
}
```

Sound good, until your program runs without any error but does nothing because you just forgot that `doStuff()` actually looks like:

```
func doStuff() error {
    // ...
    return errors.New("woops!")
}
```

What we should do ist:

```
func main() {
    err := doStuff()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Or at least (to make it obvious):

```
func main() {
    _ = doStuff()
}
```

There are so many go tools out there like. Is there a simple way to check my code for not handled error return values?

Comment: have you tried `errcheck`? https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck

Comment: You say you're aware of the many, many tools available to do static code checking of Go code, but didn't state why any of the ones you're already aware of were an adequate solution... is there something in particular you're looking for that you've yet to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @eugecm suggested, github.com/kisielk/errcheck will do this, as will github.com/GoASTScanner/gas . Also, github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter makes it easy to download a collection of linters and run them in parallel, and includes both of the above.

So,

```
go get github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
gometalinter --install
gometalinter
```

would download gometalinter, which will then install a number of error and style checkers and run them in parallel, reporting the results.

The relevant results from your example would be like:

```
main.go:13::warning: Errors unhandled.,LOW,HIGH (gas)
main.go:13::warning: error return value not checked (doStuff()) (errcheck)
```

I recommend gometalinter because it gives results like the above, where running errcheck on a bare command just says `main.go:13:10  doStuff()` (because errcheck is a program that *only* checks for unchecked error return values, so no additional information is really necessary).

Comment: https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter is deprecated by https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint.